# cuando ingreso dos datos iguales en mi string el Split(';').ToList() lo agrega a la lista como uno solo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, controller, split

tengo un inconveniente con el Split(;).ToList().

cada vez que guardo dos datos iguales dentro de una variable string, la función Split(;) los agrega a la lista como uno solo.

Ej: si envío tres cantidades (1; 2; 2;), el split me agrega a mi lista un arreglo con: (1,2).

este es mi código dentro del controlador:

string productos= model.productos;

```
            List<string> listaProductos = productos.Split(';').Distinct().ToList();
            listaProductos = listaProductos.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

Como podría solucionar esto?

de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Tendrás el código que esta fallando?

Comment: string productos= model.productos;

                List<string> listaProductos = productos.Split(';').ToList();
                listaProductos = listaProductos.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar el código que sirve para futuras referencias. En lo que respecta al problema que estas tendiendo, este reside en el Distinct que tienes cuando obtienes la lista de productos, no cuando la divides.

Comment: En efecto, tienes toda la razón!!! funcionó perfectamente quitando el Disctinct.. Muchísimas Gracias!!!!

Comment: Excelente, dejo la respuesta para futura referencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas quitar el `Distinct()` de tu consulta

Comment: @RafaelBautistaMartinez date una vuelta por los comentarios de la pregunta.